# Understanding the projective bundle of a locally free sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Projective bundles have come up in a text I am reading.

Let $ V \subset \mathbb{P}(E) $ be a hypersurface equipped with the natural projection $ \pi: V \rightarrow S. $ Then $ \pi = \rho|_{V} $ is a conic bundle if every fibre $ \pi^{-1}(s) \subset \mathbb{P}^{2} $ is a conic in $ \mathbb{P}^{2}. $

I have seen these two statement in a text, and I have a few questions:

> Let $ S $ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $ \operatorname{dim}S \geq 2, \; \rho:E \rightarrow S $ an (algebraic) vector bundle of rank $ 3,\; \rho: \mathbb{P}(E) \rightarrow S $ its projectivization, that is, a locally trivial $ \mathbb{P}^{2}$-bundle over $ S. $
>
> Let $ \varepsilon $ be a sheaf of sections of the dual bundle $ E^{*} \rightarrow S. $ Then $ \mathbb{P}(E) $ coincides with the projective bundle $ \mathbb{P}(\varepsilon). $

I feel that I don't really know what a projective bundle is. In particular, I'd like to know what $ \mathbb{P}(\varepsilon) $ is.

I have some crumbs of information here but they are scheme-theoretic. The work I am doing does not involve schemes, and I would appreciate a more "classical" view. For now, here is the information I have from reading:

I know that if $ X $ is a scheme, and $ S $ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of graded $ \mathcal{O}_{X}$-algebras, then $$ S = \bigoplus_{d \in \mathbb{N}} S_{d}, $$ where $ S_{0} = X. $ Furthermore, $ \mathbb{P}(\varepsilon) = \operatorname{Proj}S $ is the projective bundle over $ X $ associated to $ \varepsilon. $

I have a vague understanding of this because I know a bit about projective schemes, but it's still unclear. A more "classical" picture will be very helpful.

Comment: You haven't really asked anything specific, so it's hard to know what to write. The idea is that if you have a vector bundle $\pi:E \to X$ of rank $n+1$, you can trivialize it over an open cover $\left\{ U_i \right\}$ so that $\pi^{-1}(U_i) \cong U_i \times \mathbb C^{n+1}$. One can then of course apply the usual projective space construction on the second factor to obtain $U_i \times \mathbb P^n$. Tracking the gluing data through this construction, you can "reassemble" your base space $X$ along with the projective spaces that are the fibers over each point to obtain...

Comment: ...a map $\mathbb P(E) \to X$ whose fibers are all copies of $\mathbb P^n$. Does this clear anything up? Also, just as $\mathbb P^n$ comes with the line bundle $\mathcal O(1)$ that allows you to define the degree of a subvariety, you get a (no longer necessarily globally ample) bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(1)$ which restricts to the ordinary (ample) $\mathcal O(1)$ on each fiber. This allows you to define the notion of a conic in a fiber of a projective bundle.

Comment: @TabesBridges I think I'm following much of what you are saying. One thing I don't quite see is how the restricted line bundle $ \mathcal{O}(1) $ allows us to define the notion of a conic in a fiber of a projective bundle.

Comment: There are a few (basically equivalent) ways of phrasing this. One is that the vanishing locus of a section of the restricted $\mathcal O(1)$ is (by definition) a hyperplane in the fiber, so a conic in the fiber is a subvariety (of the fiber) which meets a general such hyperplane (in the fiber) in two points. Perhaps more relevant to your situation is that for $E \to S$ a rank $3$ vector bundle, a conic bundle is the zero locus of a section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(2)$.